# How do you Read from a text file?

Tags: java

For some reason this is not working, I'm quite new to java so I am probably being naive.

```
public class CheckScore extends quiz{
    public void CheckScore() {
        String filename = "Data_CS";{

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))){
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) == "potato") {
                System.out.print("vde");
                System.out.print(line);
            }
            } 
         catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }        
    }
}
```

Comment: use `(line = br.readLine()).equals("potato")` if it only read the file if the content of the line is potato. normally you use `(line = br.readLine()) !=null`

Comment: Please try to be more specific with your question; read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong `equals`.

`==` means are the instances that these variables represent the same.

`.equals(value)` means are the values that these variables hold equal.

Hope the explanation helped you.

Comment: Just a quick add on, would you know how for the program to print the like below it as well

Answer (score 0):

With string you can use '=='
So you can use this :

```
 line=br.readLine();
 while ((line.equals("potato")) {
            System.out.print("vde");
            System.out.print(line);
            line=br.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: thank you, it works

Comment: Good :D 
If it's work you can accept to show the solution to the others :)